# How to rotate context 90 degrees and set the origin to the upper left corner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics

What I am trying is to rotate context 90 degrees and set the origin to the upper left corner. This is how I try to do it:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);

    CGContextRotateCTM(c, (-90.0 * M_PI/180.0)); // 90 degrees
    CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -rect.size.height, 0);
    CGContextAddRect(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

What I expect is that the rectangle would be fully visible in the upper left corner. But here it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I tested your code, and the rectangle is fully visible in the lower left corner of the view (which is what I would expect from the code). - Perhaps you can explain (or show a sketch) how you would like the text to appear.

Comment: you tried on a real phone or on the simulator? I try to get the rectangle fully visible in the upper left corner from the perspective of a 90 degrees right rotated device.

Comment: I tried on simulator. The origin is by default in the upper left corner. You rotate it by 90 degrees, and then translate it, so that the origin is now in the lower left corner.

Comment: With `CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -100, 0);` it would be visible in the top left corner (100 == width of rectangle).

Comment: Ok, then its probably a problem with the setup of my views. Anyway thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I have read your first comment once again. I assume now that your code is correct, but the view rectangle is too large. Could it be that the view is sized for a 4-inch display, and the code is executed on a 3.5-inch display? That would explain why the rectangle is only partially visible.

Comment: That is it drawRect is called with 548 points but has only 460. How do I change this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25038/discussion-between-martin-r-and-tmanthey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually correct. The rotation+translation moves the origin of the coordinate system to the lower left corner of the view, with the x-axis pointing upward, and the y-axis pointing right. If you rotate the device by 90 degrees, then the origin appears in the upper left corner, as you indented.

The problem is that the view rectangle is too large for the display. As you said in the discussion, the rectangle's height is 548, which is the height of the 4-inch display (minus status bar). Therefore, if you start the app on a 4-inch display, the rectangle is clipped at the bottom.

You have to adjust the size/autosize options of the view so that it is displayed correctly on all devices.